# amChart map chart with time frame selection capabilities

Tags: amcharts, ammap

I was wondering if anyone did something similar or if it's even possible using amChart maps and using chartScrollbar or some other scrollbar to simulate time frame selection and to update tooltips over countries on scroll.

[image]

<-------O================0------------->
Scroll bar goes at the bottom.

Comment: Have you looked at the [motion chart and map demo](http://www.amcharts.com/inspiration/motion-chart/) on the AmCharts site? It pretty much does what you're asking. Just view the source and pull out what you need for the map-oriented stuff.

Comment: this looks pretty good although I'm not sure if I can access the source.

Comment: Right click -> view source. It's all there.